# Getting Instance Name of org with a domain

Tags: mydomain, custom-domain

How can I figure out what instance my org is on (e.g. NA6, NA7) when I have a domain setup?

I have setup the custom domain https://custom-domain-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com as shown below. If I try to get the domain using

```
System.Url.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm()
```

it is returned as

> https://custom-domain-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com

If I can't figure out the domain then sites such as http://trust.salesforce.com/trust/maintenance/ and http://trust.salesforce.com/trust/status/ are useless to me.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to http://trust.salesforce.com/trust/status/# and click '[What instance am I using?](http://trust.salesforce.com/trust/domainLookupLaunch/)'. It will show your instance name.

There have been [reports](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000hWbMAAU) that the domain lookup doesn't work all the time. If that is the case you can do a [CNAME Lookup](https://www.google.ie/search?q=cname%20lookup) on your domain instead it will return something like this:

> ;; ANSWER SECTION: custom-domain-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com. 300 IN
>   CNAME **na17**.my.salesforce.com.

Comment: Thanks. The [domain lookup page](http://trust.salesforce.com/trust/domainLookupLaunch/) doesn't seem to work for developer edition domains. I've got it to work for Production instances but not for dev editions (i.e. domains ending in **dev-ed**)

Comment: Maybe this is solution for your issue https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000hWbMAAU they advised to use nslookup in order to check CNAME record, as a last resort you can ask SFDC support.

Comment: Perfect. I've edited your Answer to include that information and also accepted it as the correct answer

Comment: New My domain lookup link: https://status.salesforce.com/status then click button "My Domain"

Answer (score 13):

A SOQL Query on the `Organization` object will provide you with your org's InstanceName, regardless of whether you're using My Domain or not:

```
String instanceName = [select InstanceName from Organization limit 1].InstanceName;

--> NA31, CS9, etc.
```

Note, ensure that you run this query in a `without sharing` annotated class, otherwise the query will only be visible to System Administrators.

Comment: I was looking for a while this, it worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: I believe that's api v31 and up only.

Answer (score 3):

You can add your org to an Environment Hub and it will display you the instance on which the org is located. To get more infos about Environment Hub (it can do a lot of other useful things for you!), check this out: https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=environment_hub_main.htm

[image]

Comment: Thank you for reply, I didn't know that something like this exists. The only drawback is that env hub is available only for:  Enterprise, Performance, and Unlimited Editions.

Comment: Yes, most of the candy comes at EE+ - I'm using the Hub since a couple of Months and it's really a cool feature, i. e. if your working with a number of different orgs. If you have a chance, try it.